# Simplifying the integral $\int \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I have the following integral that I must simplify by making two substitutions
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx,
\end{align}
one of them is
\begin{align}
y = \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1},
\end{align}
the other, however, I do not know which it may be and which comes first. I would appreciate your help

Comment: Do you can use other way? with your  first substitution, you need express all in terms of $y$, $x^4= (\frac{y+1}{y-1})^2$ and so on

Comment: @weymarandres One of the two substitutions must be $y = \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$, either the first or the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that substitution is to do$$x=\sqrt\frac{1+y}{1-y}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathrm dx=\frac1{(1-y)\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,\mathrm dy.$$Then your primitive becomes$$\int\frac y{\sqrt2\sqrt{1-y^4}}\,\mathrm dy$$and now all you have to do is $z=y^2$ and $\mathrm dz=2y\,\mathrm dy$.